# I'm making a withdraw command but discord won't let me use "with" as the command name. What do I do?

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to make a withdraw command in by economy bot, but python won't let me use "with" as the name. I think the reason why is that with is a built in python function. Can someone tell me how I can make "with" the command name in `async def with(ctx, amount=None):`?

Code:

```
@client.command()
async def with(ctx, amount = None):
```

Error:

```
  File "main.py", line 363
    async def with(ctx, amount = None):
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`with` is a reserved keyword in Python. Override the command name like

```
@client.command(name='with')
async def _with(ctx, amount = None):
```